# can't login, is God telling me something?

Tags: discussion

I thought it would be cute to use a "fake" OpenID provider, like openid.aliz.es/makeuptheusername. No password, just a cryptic username and you're good to go. I really like the idea. And if you want to make fun of it, read Richard M. Stallman's story about his MIT days.

But now, either SE or that site have a clock synchronization problem, and let me log out and try to log in to reproduce the problem, or use another browser to do the same.

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> This message has a timestamp of 12/14/2013 8:22:15 AM, which is beyond the allowable clock skew for in the future.

OK, how do I pick up my account?

Comment: Perhaps you should email SE support. I don't think anybody except the SE staff can help you.

Comment: Next time post on the main stack exchange meta: no minimum rep is required and you have the attention of the whole network not just this site. Posting on main like you did is not the right approach.

Comment: If the question is 'can't login, is God telling me something?', then, maybe, yes, but it is difficult to say what He wish you do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [account recovery system](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) to gain access to your account. Note that this is linked in the [help center section on accounts](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/account) along with how to deal with other OpenID issues.

Comment: There is no e-mail associated with  an openID provider like openid.aliz.es/. That's the point of using a fake openID provider.

Comment: @user9055 If you provided fake information there isn't much we can do through normal channels. You can try the OpenID recovery related stuff from the help center or email support and try to authenticate your claim manually. Next time use legit credentials and you won't have this problem.